# Como bloquear llamadas a metodos no POST ni GET en AWS

Tags: aws, lambda

tengo un proyecto montado sobre AWS y necesito que la URL raiz de la aplicacion web devuelva un status code de 405 para metodos que no sea ni POST ni GET. He intentado cambiar el middleware de cada proyecto lambda para que rechace esas conexiones. Pero la URL raiz sigue aceptandolas. He tocado el API gateway, no se si bien, para que deje pasar los metodos GET y POST y los ANY devuelvan un 405, pero no parece funcionar tampoco. Me podeis echar una mano?

API GATEWAY

[image: API GATEWAY]

LLAMADA POSTMAN

[image: LLAMADA POSTMAN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En API Gateway puedes, para cada endpoint, definir qué métodos son válidos, quedando el resto automáticamente deshabilitados. Puedes seguir el tutorial [aquí](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html)

Una vez hayas activado aquellos endpoints y métodos que realmente necesites, pasas a configurar las respuestas dadas por API Gateway en el caso de que se realicen conexiones con métodos no soportados.

Para esta segunda tarea tienes que ir a "Gateway Responses" y buscar la entrada "Missing Authentication Token". Aquí podrás configurar la respuesta que API Gateway enviará cuando se intente acceder a un endpoint no válido o el método no esté soportado.

Cuando hayas configurado la respuesta que esperas devolver, debes desplegar el API Gateway de nuevo para que se apliquen los cambios de forma efectiva. Para ello vuelve a la ventana de "Resources", donde defines los endpoints, despliega el botón "Actions" y selecciona "Deploy API". Indica el "stage" que quieres actualizar y listo, en unos 15-20 segundos el API Gateway empezará a devolver la salida esperada.

Comment: Hol Eferion. Perdona mi ignorancia. He creado dos methods GET y POST con type HTTP. Pero sigue sin funcionar. Asi que he creado un ANY de tipo MOCK que devuelve un 405. Pero ninguno funciona desde POSTMAN. En cambio si le doy a la opcion TEST de cada definicion de metodos, parece funcionar. No se que hago mal.

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead Los métodos que no quieras usar ... no los definas. La combinación endpoint+method que no exista en api gateway **siempre** te va a devolver el error marcado como "Missing Authentication Token". Edita la respuesta asociada a a ese error, redespliega el api y ya lo tendrías

Comment: Si defines un ANY o un PROXY+, entonces pasa a ser tu lambda la responsable de devolver el mensaje de error correspondiente

Comment: Pues sinceramente no se, juraria que hago eso. Te paso mi configuracion del API GATEWAY y mi llamada POSTMAN para que veas que sigue devolviendo un 200. Que se me esta pasando por alto? Creo que podria estar relacionado con que yo quiero bloquear la root url de mi web application. La que se publica. Y el API GATEWAY hace referencia a las llamadas a la API no a la root url. https://test.com y https://test-api.com. Podria ser? Muchas gracias

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead Si estás con dominio, puede ser que haya otro servicio dándote esas respuestas ... tras un dominio puede haber muchos servicios escuchando. Prueba a activar todos los logs de api gateway, lanza una petición de las que deberían fallar y comprueba si eso genera una entrada de log en api gateway

Comment: Si no hay log, entonces es que la petición no le está llegando a api gateway. Si hay log, entonces mira a ver si el log te dice que la petición se redirecciona correctamente o si se trata de un error. Lo suyo es que te dijese que es un error y ahí es donde te debería dar la respuesta que hayas configurado con la respuesta que te he dado, si no da error entonces es que  la petición la estás redirigiendo a una lambda ... y esa sería la lambda la responsable de la respuesta

Comment: Perdon por esta pregunta. Pero como se activa los LOGs? Disculpa

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead "AWS API Gateway -> seleccionas tu api gateway -> Stages -> Logs/Tracing y ahí en CloudWatch Logs elige "Full Request and Response Logs". Después dale a "Save changes". Para ver los logs, quédate con el identificador de tu api gateway (lo puedes sacar de la url de AWS "https://[REGION].console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=[REGION]#/apis/[API_GATEWAY_ID]/stages/XXX"), ve a CloudWatch y busca el log **API-Gateway-Execution-Log_[API_GATEWAY_ID]**

Comment: Sinceramente, muchas gracias por las molestias que te estas tomando. En Cloudwatch hay un apartado de logs, pero ponen 3 opciones que no reconozco: Log group, log insights, live tail. No se buscar el log ahi segun dices.

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead log group. Te sugiero hacer algun curso de AWS antes de avanzar más. AWS tiene muchos servicios con miles de opciones. Necesitas entender un poco mejor cómo funciona para poder desplegar servicios correctamente

Comment: Y quita los ANY. Los ANY aceptan cualquier método. Quita esos ANY y define únicamente los métodos que necesitas

Comment: Los ANY ya estan quitados. Pero entiendo.... Gracias por las molestias que te has tomado :). Si posteas una respuesta la puntuare con un +1 por tu esfuerzo :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146635/discussion-between-eferion-and-kenzo-gilead).